# How to add a child dynamically and efficiently whithout rerendering parents in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rerender

I know we can add a child dynamically like this：

```
...
{show && <View/>}
...
```

But the performance is too bad. I mean maybe I will add a child for 30 times or more in one second(depending on the business logic).

For example: I'd like add a child every time when a ScrollView scrolls 30 pixels.
I'm writing a highly performance List component which is much better than FlatList. I need to know how to add a child dynamically and efficiently whithout rerendering parents. Is there a method like "React.createElement" which can add a child without rerendering parents

Answer (score 1):

The performance of ScrollView is not great, because it renders all the children at once. If you are looking to render children as the user scrolls down, I would suggest using FlatList, the performance and user experience is significantly better.

Here is a link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Starting off you will want to create a function that returns the view you would like to see. Render the FlatList component and pass two props to it, data and renderItem. renderItem will be function that returns the view you wish to see, and data will be the collection that you are mapping over.

```
`//this is the component you want to render for each child
function MyComponent({ name, text, image }){
  return (
    <View>
        however you want the child to look like 
    </View>
  )
}
// this is the function that you pass to FlatList, and your props to.
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <MyComponent {...item}/>
  )
}
// rendering the FlatList component
render(){
  const data = getData() // an object

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  )
}`
```

Comment: It seems that you do not understand what I mean. I'm writing a highly performance List component which is much better than FlatList.  I need to know how to add a child dynamically and efficiently whithout rerendering parents. Is there a method like "React.createElement" which can add a child without rerendering parents

Comment: If the method does not exist, I only create more Views on initialization.Just improve the performance.

Comment: Oh okay, I see now. Thanks for clarifying. I get what you mean, I have not personally come across that method, although it would be awesome